# Adobe Creative SDK - nineoldAndroidsLibrary Issue

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I have integrated Adobe SDK in my app.OK previously the whole app with ImageUIEditor was working fine until i see this error now

> ```
> Failed to resolve: com.nineoldandroids:library+
> ```

And this error is making me sick.I have been messing up for the last 7 hours,but couldnt find any solution any where.
This error belong to the

> creative-sdk-repo

folder

Comment: Same thing is happening to me

Comment: last week it was working fine, until i opened the project again ,today.I have sent them an email and commented on different forums, lets see if they resolve this.

Comment: Please provide the email so i can sent them to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to try that have worked:

**1.**
In `build.gradle`, allow `mavenCentral()`.

**2.**
In `build.gradle`, add the following code to your `android` block:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    }
}
```

---

**#1** should do the trick. Keep **#2** as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced some more issues in the project , then i figured out i forgot to add point number 1, suggested by @AshRayan
So , if any body's wondering just add this to your build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aars'
        }
        maven {
            url "${project.rootDir}/creativesdk-repo/release" // Location of the CSDK repo
        }
    } }
```

Happy Coding !